# How to use GeoDataApi.getPlaceById?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

**Question**:
What is the cleanest way to create a `Place` object from an ID string?

I want make some `place` objects out of hard-coded ids.
Think something like `Place place1 = new Place("ChIJS_zBNNbXAhURy-FuRT5ib9k")`, but that of-course doesn't work.

I came across `GeoDataApi.getPlaceById`, but the documentation is confusing.

That API is usually used for looking up whatever a user inputs (optionally with autocompletion), but I need something smaller and cleaner (think: unit testing purposes)

---

**My research:**
[How to get a Place by ID](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details#get-place)

> To get a place by ID, call [`GeoDataApi.getPlaceById`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html#public-methods), passing one or more place IDs.
>
> The API returns a [`PlaceBuffer`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceBuffer) in a [`PendingResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult). The [`PlaceBuffer`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceBuffer) contains a list of [`Place`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place) objects that match the supplied place IDs.

Documentation:

[Place](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place)
(the object required)

[PlaceBuffer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceBuffer)
(convertable to a Place)

[PendingResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult)

[getPlaceById](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html#public-methods)
(returns a PendingResult)

---

**What I'm stuck with**:
I can't find an elegant way to turn a `PendingResult` in to a `PlaceBuffer`.

> The API returns a `PlaceBuffer` in a `PendingResult`.

...

> The final result object from a `PendingResult<R>` is of type `R`, which can be retrieved in one of two ways.
>
> - via blocking calls to `await()`, or `await(long, TimeUnit)`, or
> - via a callback by passing in an object implementing interface `ResultCallback` to `setResultCallback(ResultCallback)`.

A callback is too messy, and I can't find any code that uses `await` to learn from it.

Comment: I found an example at http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/

Comment: @xomena I already saw that & have read that. Some `ctrl+f` helps in such big code snippets. This hardly helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily turn a `PendingResult` from `getPlaceById` into a `PlaceBuffer`.  You simply call the `await()` method:

```
PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> result = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(
        mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
PlaceBuffer placeBuffer = result.await();
```

(You could of course do that in one line if you prefer.)

There are examples of calling `GeoDataApi.getPlaceByID` and `PendingResult<PlaceBuffer>.await` in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places.

Comment: `The returned result object can have an additional failure mode of INTERRUPTED.` - how do you deal with that?

Comment: The same way you'd deal with any other failure status in `PlaceBuffer`.  E.g. `if (!placeBuffer.getStatus().isSuccess()) { reportErrorSomewhere(placeBuffer.getStatus().toString()); }`

Comment: **Note**: pendingResult is old, see API [11.2.0](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details)